# How to create a search bar in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

If possible, could anyone guide me as how to make a simple search bar in android? I kind of got lost looking at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableConfiguration) link  and I was hoping someone could help me out. Is it possible for someone to help me explain how to create a search bar or kind of give me a better understanding on the tutorial implements it all? Like I'm not sure where to put all the code they give you in what files and what not. Thanks!

Comment: For which purpose you want to create search bar, here is some link that may help you http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/search-interface/ http://matthias.jimdo.com/2011/06/06/how-to-add-search-functionality-to-your-android-application/